# Checking the performance of two ways to append string in Perl

Tags: perl

I can use the two following ways in Perl:

```
my $str = "hello";
my $o1 = $str." world";
my $o2 = "$str world";
```

They do the same thing, although I was wondering if they are the same when speaking about performance. How can I check it? is there a special online tool?

Comment: You could try [`Benchmark`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark)

Answer (score 8):

[Benchmark](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark) is the way to do this.

The two methods you're describing are called concatenation and interpolation, so we'll use those names as labels in the test.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark;

my $str = 'hello';

# Run this two subroutines for at least 3 CPU seconds.
# That "negative seconds" parameter is possibly the worst
# interface in all of Perl!
timethese(-3, {
  concat => sub { $str . ' world' },
  interp => sub { "$str world" },
});
```

And the results...

```
$ perl benchmark
Benchmark: running concat, interp for at least 3 CPU seconds...
    concat:  4 wallclock secs ( 3.16 usr +  0.00 sys =  3.16 CPU) @ 32680513.61/s (n=103270423)
    interp:  3 wallclock secs ( 3.22 usr +  0.00 sys =  3.22 CPU) @ 29918605.90/s (n=96337911)
```

Concatenation is slightly faster [**Note:** as pointed out in the comments, that's note really true - any differences are well within the margin of error for these tests]. But note that we needed to run around a hundred million tests in order to find this tiny difference. So I don't think you really need to worry here.

Comment: I've done some more experiments and could not find any significant difference. Concatenation seems to come out slightly ahead in most but not all runs, but the spread of results is much larger than the difference between concatenation and interpolation. Also, note that a subroutine call has much more overhead than a simple operation like string concatenation. For microbenchmarks it can be helpful to include a loop instead, e.g. `sub { ...  for 1 .. 1E6 }`.

Comment: Re "*Concatenation is slightly faster*", No, they literally produce exactly the same code.  Your analysis is flawed: A difference of 0.000,000,02 s is well within the error margin

Answer (score 3):

[Benchmark](http://p3rl.org/Benchmark) is usually used to benchmark code. It's good to also test that the code being benchmarked gives the same output, so I included [Test::More](http://p3rl.org/Test::More).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Benchmark qw{ cmpthese };

my $var = join "", 'a' .. 'z';
my $string = uc $var;

my $dot = "\$string . ' $var'";
my $dq  = qq("\$string $var");

use Test::More tests => 1;
is  eval $dot,
    eval $dq,
    'same';

cmpthese(-3, {
         dot => $dot,
         dq  => $dq,
});
```

The results from repeated runs seem random, so the difference is probably negligible:

```
1..1
ok 1 - same
          Rate dot  dq
dot 19583087/s  -- -6%
dq  20725520/s  6%  --

1..1
ok 1 - same
          Rate  dq dot
dq  18925046/s  -- -7%
dot 20246124/s  7%  --
```

Answer (score 3):

They're not merely similar; they both produce exactly the same code.

```
$ for v in 5.10 5.12 5.14 5.16 5.18 5.20 5.22 5.24 5.26 5.28
do
   diff -u \
      <( "$v"t/bin/perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'my $x = $str . " world"' 2>&1 ) \
      <( "$v"t/bin/perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'my $x = "$str world"'    2>&1 ) \
      && echo "$v: identical" \
      || echo "$v: different"
done
5.10: identical
5.12: identical
5.14: identical
5.16: identical
5.18: identical
5.20: identical
5.22: identical
5.24: identical
5.26: identical 
5.28: identical
```

As such, there will be no difference in performance.

By the way, you're not thinking straight if you're wondering about the performance difference of those two; you should be thinking about readability/maintainability.

Comment: Do you have 5.28 available for testing? It has some improvements to string concatenation that might be used here.

Comment: I measure 5.28 as being more than twice as fast as 5.26 :-)

Comment: @Shawn, 5.28 fails to build on my machine, but I don't see what they would suddenly start being different there. The optimization you're talking about would actually remove differences if anything. It really only kicks in if you concatenate more than two things, though.

Comment: The 5.28 multiconcat optimisation also makes a big difference for my $x = ..., since it optimises away the assign and the padmy ops. (And yes, on 5.28, both the concat and stringify versions still compile to the same code as each other)